# Export Big Query to Google cloud storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I like to export Big query to Google cloud storage. Other than Export Query is there any other option to do the same.

My data is near about 2 GB and in export query it split in different files the data as data is big. So I have to export to only in one file. So please help me on the same.

Comment: Not "natively" - as the documentation says, "You can export up to 1 GB of table data to a single file. If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, use a wildcard to export the data into multiple files." Have you considered exporting to multiple files and then combining them? You say "So I have to export to only in one file" - is that a hard requirement? Could you potentially change whatever is reading the data to handle multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

I think as for now is not possible what you want to do. The documentation of Big query is the following:

When you export data from BigQuery, note the following:

You cannot export table data to a local file, to Sheets, or to Drive. The only supported export location is Cloud Storage. For information on saving query results, see Downloading and saving query results.

You can export up to 1 GB of table data to a single file. If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, use a wildcard to export the data into multiple files. When you export data to multiple files, the size of the files will vary.

You cannot export nested and repeated data in CSV format. Nested and repeated data are supported for Avro, JSON, and Parquet exports.
When you export data in JSON format, INT64 (integer) data types are encoded as JSON strings to preserve 64-bit precision when the data is read by other systems.

You cannot export data from multiple tables in a single export job.

You cannot choose a compression type other than GZIP when you export data using the Cloud console.

When you export data to a Cloud Storage bucket configured with a retention policy, BigQuery might fail to write the files to the bucket. Consider relaxing the retention policy for the duration of the export jobs.

When you export a table in JSON format, the symbols <, >, and & are converted by using the unicode notation \uNNNN, where N is a hexadecimal digit. For example, profit&loss becomes profit\u0026loss. This unicode conversion is done to avoid security vulnerabilities.

The order of exported table data is not guaranteed unless you use the EXPORT DATA statement and specify an ORDER BY clause in the query_statement.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Answer (score 0):

You have a range of exporting data other than using `EXPORT DATA` documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data).

I personally like to use Python

```py
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
project = "bigquery-public-data"
dataset_id = "samples"
table_id = "shakespeare"

destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "shakespeare.csv")
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location="US",
)  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

print(
    "Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a common requirement and a common blocker. There is nothing out of the box but I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/get-a-single-one-csv-file-with-bigquery-export-956d2a147886) where I use Cloud Workflow to aggregate all the files generated by the export statement.